# Switch visual not changing

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift3 and have the following variable `str8redpickteamreminder` which is either 1 or 0.  I also have a switch called whichthe code can can be seen at the bottom of the question.

I thought I could use the following code which would change the visuals of the switch:

```
    if str8redpickteamreminder == 1 {
        self.teamSelectNotif = true
    }
    else {
        self.teamSelectNotif = false
    }
```

Yet the switches just stay as on when the code is run.  How can I make the switch linked to teamSelectNotif show as false in the app programatically?

Any help is appreciated.

Switch Code:

```
@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if sender.isOn == true {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            teamSelectNotif = true
            print(toggleUpdate(toggle: "str8redpickteamreminder", setting: 1))
        case 3:
            resultsNotif = true
            print(toggleUpdate(toggle: "str8redresults", setting: 1))
        default:
            break



        }}
        else if sender.isOn == false {
            switch sender.tag {
            case 1:
                teamSelectNotif = false

            case 3:
                resultsNotif = false
            default:
                break
        }}
    }
```

Comment: If `str8redpickteamreminder` is only ever 1 or 0, why model it as an integer? Make it a `Bool`, then it's just `self.resultsNotif = str8redpickteamreminder`. Although what relation does `resultsNotif` have to `teamSelectNotif`?

Comment: str8redpickteamreminder is from a database which stores it as a tinyint.  The resultNotif should be teamSelectNotif.  Will change right away.  But even if I put self. teamSelectNotif = false it does not change it's visual state.

Comment: Just because you persist the value as an integer doesn't mean that it should be one in your model – you should convert it to a `Bool`, as that's a stronger type for it.

Comment: OK, I will convert it.  But how does the switch change visually on the screen?

Comment: You haven't told us what this switch is yet (or even what platform you're working with) – I'm going to take a wild guess that it's a `UISwitch`. Do you have an IBOutlet hooked up to it? What's the name of this outlet?

Comment: Apologies, have added the code which should help explain the setup.

Comment: I'm still unclear on exactly what you're trying to achieve – please could you update your question detailing exactly what you want to happen in the code you've now posted (i.e the name of the `UISwitch` you want to change the state of, and when you want this to happen). `teamSelectNotif` is not a `UISwitch`, it's just a `Bool` from your above code. Also what does `toggleUpdate(toggle:)` do?

Comment: Have tried to make it clearer but I do not think I am getting my wording to match your understanding.  In short I just want the switch on the screen to be able to be updated programatically rather than the user touching it.  Reason being is I want to set it's initial state when the view loads so that it matches previously saved settings in the database.

Comment: "*the switch linked to teamSelectNotif*" – but `teamSelectNotif` isn't a `UISwitch` from your above code, it's just a `Bool`. What you need to do is hook up an IBOutlet from the UISwitch in your storyboard/XIB, and then set the `isOn` property of that outlet.

Comment: Many thanks. Will try that this evening.  Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Apologies for slow reply but actual day job got in the way lol.  Anyway, "What you need to do is hook up an IBOutlet from the UISwitch in your storyboard/XIB" inspired the solution.  Could you please put that as your answer and I will accept it.